# How to group to a runnable folder on a solution has 3 layer model C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, build

I've finished a software for my subject on school. It's built by visual studio 2015. It's using 3 layer model (GUI-BUS-DAO-DTO). I tried to build a release to submit for marking score but it builds separate folders on \bin\release for each project ( 4 folders for GUI-BUS-DAO-DTO) But I only want 1 folder has all components to run for solution. So how can I do it?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your project properties you can add some xcopy commands in the post-build event and copy files to any place you like. There you can also use the additional environment variables listed in the bottom of the editor window.

#### Example

```
xcopy /f /y /d "$(TargetPath)" "$(SolutionDir)$(SolutionName)\$(OutDir)Libraries\"
```

- `/f` means that the source and destination path will be shown in output
- `/y` overwrites a file if it already exists
- `/d` overwrites only files if they are newer
- `$(TargetPath)` environment variable that contains the path to the projects output.
- `$(SolutionDir)` environment variable that contains the path to the solution directory.

The full list of variables can be seen in the editor window.

Comment: Thanks but anyone help me more detail ? I don't understand because I'm just noob in C# and visual.